# hiding 'internal' dataset from documentation (R CMD check)

Tags: r, documentation

I'm currently R CMD checking the documentation for a package I wrote. In one of the functions, I use an auxiliary data object called 'labels' to merge to the user's input. I don't want the user to know about this dataset (it's just there to help provide proper output). How can I hide this dataset / code object so that the following warnings are avoided:

```
* checking for missing documentation entries ... WARNING
Undocumented code objects:
  ‘labels’
Undocumented data sets:
  ‘labels’ ‘spain.1900’
```

Comment: Don't put it in `data/`, put it in `R/sysdata.rda`

Comment: Thanks hadley, that indeed solves the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Just providing hadley's comment as answer for the sake of closing the question. If you like it, vote his comment, not this answer.*

Save the data as sysdata.rda inside R/ rather than in data/

```
labels <- read.xlsx("/Users/.../some_file.xlsx", sheetName = "some_sheet")
save(file="./R/sysdata.rda", labels)
```